# Do not bring up posts in review that I myself flagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

If *my* flag was the reason a post got into a review queue, it should not be presented for *me* to review, too.

I can not flag it again (yet can change my opinion and do another thing). But the fact I flagged it before means I already stated my opinion on it.

An example is: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6191035

Another option (in addition to the subj) is to include my flag into review results if I have the review rights.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Can't reasonably complete a low quality question review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192629/cant-reasonably-complete-a-low-quality-question-review) and its dup: [Review of “Low Quality Posts” when out of close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145402/review-of-low-quality-posts-when-out-of-close-votes)

Comment: To clarify, *your flag* did not cause it to appear in the Low Quality Posts queue. A recommend closure flag would cause it to appear in the Close Votes queue. There was a VLQ flag on the question, and *that* is what bumped it into Low Quality Posts. Your real request is that if you've previously cast any flag on the post, you shouldn't be displayed that post.

Comment: Ultimately I think this is a major flaw in the use of the queue for questions. We moderators have long argued that VLQ flags should not be allowed on questions, because the Low Quality Posts queue is meant for **deletion** of crappy content that can't be salvaged - it shouldn't be used as a secondary Close Votes queue. If we stop trying to have users do things that the queue *isn't designed for*, then this problem becomes obsolete. Fixing this "bug" would be fixing a broken arm with a bunch of band-aids.

Comment: How does the review process on questions even work? As far as I can tell: the exact reasons given for recommended closure don't matter; they only need to reach a quorum, and any exceeding ones merely advance the entry in the Close Votes queue.

Comment: @animuson The problem is the LQRQ won't let you delete questions!

Comment: @animuson since I don't see such posts anymore, I presume this is [tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, this has been fixed.

Comment: Specifically, Triage replaced LQP (for questions only) when it was introduced.

Comment: No it hasn't. I got dinged by this just the other day(Jan. 2019). I went to flag the post and there was a message indicating that I had already flagged it, selected no action, and got a "Stop, Look and Listen" warning.

Comment: @KevinBowen The issue has been fixed more than two years ago, and I have never seen it since, being an active member the entire time. If something similar has happened, this is clearly another bug. Please report this as another issue.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I could. Is there a way to look in my review history to view a failed audit? None of my 'No Action Needed' reviews indicate a failure,

Comment: @KevinBowen It should be in your browsing history at least.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/912042 At the time of review, the NAA radio was greyed out and there was a message that I had already flagged it. Hope this helps. Thanks.