# "No action needed" appears ambiguous to reviewers if they already raised a flag on that specific post from outside the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags, review-suspension

## Situation

My review privileges have been suspended and the message states some posts which led to the suspension:

[image: screenshot]

Here are the links you can click on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21778949
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21782829
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21767911
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21768263

All four mentioned posts suffer from the same issue described in this post.

---

## Problem

When reviewing the posts linked above, I clicked on "Flag" to raise the appropriate flag. However, I wasn't able to do so, as apparently I already had done that before - from outside the review queue. These flags had all been considered helpful later on:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

---

I was not able to click on "Done" since I hadn't done anything from inside the review queue. The "Done" button was disabled. (The "Done" button will be enabled, as soon as you reload the review page.)

Also, I **did** review the post, so "Skip" doesn't seem right to me either.

So I clicked "No action needed" as in "No **further** action needed". (Because I had already raised the appropriate flag and no **further** action was needed.) "No action needed" did not sound to me like it was validating the post. It did not sound contradictory to my previously raised flag.

---

## Feature Request

- The review queue prohibits me from raising a flag, so it "knows" that I already raised a flag. The information that I already took action is there. Therefore "Done" should be made available to click on, as soon as "Flag" is clicked in the review queue window.
- Make it more obvious that "No action needed" should never be clicked if there is anything wrong with the post even if a flag has already been raised. Like [renaming it from "No action needed" to "Looks fine"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378356/when-reviewing-late-answers-or-first-posts-is-there-a-reason-the-button-is-call?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: When you find a post you already moderated, just refresh the page. The Done button should appear.

Comment: Note that you were banned manually by a moderator for 4 reviews, not just one.

Comment: @Jayjayyy the correct action would be to skip those reviews if you've already flagged them.

Comment: Skip allows someone else to take action within the review system. Clicking on no action needed takes the post out of review. Unless and until that changes, clicking on no action needed makes the situation worse.

Comment: Yes there is, raising a flag in the review system keeps the post in the review system for other non-moderators to close. That's a good thing. Clicking No action needed terminates that whole thing and forces moderators to get involved.

Comment: If you say “ no action needed” you are saying the post is fine. If you flagged, it follows you believe it is not fine.

Comment: Because most people don't flag outside the review system and then go to review and encounter those same posts again. Just do things in the opposite order, do reviews in the review system and then when you've done all the reviews you can or want to today, you can begin flagging outside review.

Comment: @Jayjayyy Lots and *lots* of reviewers have no problem clicking "no action needed" only when no action is needed on a post.  And when reviewers click "no action needed" on posts that *do* actually require moderation action, they're getting banned from review until they correct their behavior.  Seems like the system is working.  If we "didn't hold it against reviewers" when then made a mistake and indicated no moderation action was needed on posts *that required moderation action* then they wouldn't learn to correct their mistakes.

Comment: We're on the same team @Jay :) Thanks for your energy and motivation, don't take our disagreement as a rebukal. We're here to share our experience with you, and we seem to be able to navigate through reviews correctly.

Comment: @Jayjayyy It was obvious to lots of other people.  I never said that the site was perfect.  I'm just saying that your proposed change is actively harmful.  It's important for people to be informed when they do something wrong, rather than being told that their incorrect action was correct.

Comment: @Jayjayyy Lots of people actively review and don't get review banned for choosing "no action needed" on posts that they feel require moderation action.

Comment: @Jayjayyy None.  Because they know that if the a posts merits flagging, they aren't supposed to click "no action needed".  By definition, the people that know they aren't supposed to do that *aren't going to do that* (barring occasional misclicks, which happen).

Comment: So, in that same "weird" situation, I likely would have played it safe and clicked "skip". Skip is your friend whenever something doesn't "feel" right. I agree it could have been clearer, and I could stand against the system not showing you your already flagged posts, but I don't think we should "not hold it against someone"

Comment: @Jayjayyy, In future, I suggest asking such questions on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Contributors there are more likely to respond reasonably *even if they disagree with you*. Back-and-forth in comments isn't helpful, but it's the local currency here. Your suggestion is valid, even if there's an argument against your proposal.

Comment: @Jayjayyy Well the fact I would click on Flag and it would tell me "you can't raise a flag" would have definitely made me fall back to my fail-safe "skip". Honestly I do believe the proper solution is just to not offer you these reviews instead of changing the UI for this edge case. Considering how often the situation happens (less than 1% maybe?), changing the UI for the other 99% of times feels overkill. Especially since we can avoid the whole edge case by simply not showing you these

Comment: [Posts should not be shown to the reviewer if the reviewer has already flagged the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276416/4639281), this is a bug.

Answer (score 11):

**Flags made from outside of the review queue are already taken into account**. Simply refresh the page to see the effect on the review buttons. What happened was that:

- User opens review window.
- User flags reviewed post from another tab, while the first window stays opened.
- User clicks "No action needed" on the now outdated post.

Refresh the review queue, and be done with it. No need for live refresh of review queues.

---

Take the occasion to profit of the holidays! (If you happen to have those at this time of the year.)

I disagree with your proposal. I believe that reviewers should be able to show **consistency**. If, when presented with the same post, you can't consistently arrive to the same conclusion about its quality, then your results up until now were mostly a fluke anyway.

But apparently that's not all there is to the situation here.

---

From comment:

> You review a question, try to raise a flag which is not possible. So you have to choose between "No action needed" and "Skip". Because you cannot click on button "Done" because it is not active. "Skip" seems wrong, because you did review the post. You're saying you still think it's obvious that clicking on "No action needed" is wrong?

I have very often have been presented with that situation, where you flag - or vote on - a post outside of the review queue, and always have refreshed the review page, so for me at least, that "no action needed" is the wrong choice was always very evident.

Doing a *review*, is not the same as moderating the site when organically coming across posts. Reviews have much effects than casting a flag on a post, are counted for posts ordering on the questions lists (note that this is a personal hypothesis based on years of using the site and its various interfaces, flags surely have effects on many things, but reviews have a special place as far as moderation activity is concerned.)

So yes, I believe that "No action needed" is not the right action to do on the post, when presented with it, and when it's not in a shape where no actions are needed. Basically, act on the post you *see*.

Comment: @Jayjayyy: You took an action; therefore "no action needed" is inappropriate. Just because the action wasn't one of the options presented doesn't mean no action was needed. His point is basically that if you took an action before that has yet to bear fruit, then the action is still needed, even if you've already taken it.

Comment: @Jayjayyy I tried it just now, refreshing the first posts review page with an active flag on a question allows the "I'm done" button to be clicked. (don't worry, I flagged a close worthy post, no question have been harmed in the making of this test) So basically, it already does what you want. If your feature request is live polling refresh on all pages Stack Overflow, I believe that is really overkill... just refresh the page manually :)

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm...

Reviews are actually pretty broken given that fishy reviews or audits (in general) can be fairly easily detected or spotted.  Their only intention is to ensure that you're paying attention to what actions you're taking, and by and large, you *did* pay attention the first time when you realized that you couldn't flag the questions again because you already had.

**That was the smoking gun.**  That should've tipped you off right there and should've given you impetus to realize that something was off.

The tricky part is I'm not entirely sure how to *satisfy* this review.  I would imagine that doing anything along the lines of positively validating the post would be a bad thing, so any upvotes or comments or even "No Action Needed" would probably be the Wrong Thing™ to do.

*Maybe* by downvoting the post, the review would have been successful since that is an action which negatively validates the post.

Going to say I mostly agree with you on this one since the review should be unambiguous on what steps to do in order to fulfill it.  It *may* even be a bug given that flagging *should* be a negative validation of the post which should've been enough to satisfy the review.

Comment: This wasn't an audit, they were manually banned by a mod for four live reviews.

Comment: @Kendra:  Fair enough.  I should add some more nuance to this answer (or at least remove the mentions of "audit" then).

Comment: @TinyGiant:  Yeah, I had a hunch that it might be.  There's no satisfying way to resolve the review if you've already flagged it since that is always going to be a one-way operation.   Hopefully this gets overturned.