# When reviewing late answers or first posts, is there a reason the button is called "No action needed"? Can it be labelled "Looks fine" instead?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-interface, review-suspension

As pointed out to me in the comments to [my previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378353/dont-hold-it-against-reviewers-when-they-click-on-no-action-needed-if-they-al), the button <kbd>No action needed</kbd> does not mean what I though it means. I clicked on <kbd>No action needed</kbd> even though I raised a flag from outside the review queue process. **That was wrong, I should have reloaded the page which would supposedly have made <kbd>Done</kbd> available.** I know that now.

But it doesn't invalidate the request to improve the other button's label. I only clicked on <kbd>No action needed</kbd> because it was literally what had been the case: No (further) action was needed, because I had already flagged the post.

<kbd>No action needed</kbd> did not sound to me like it was validating the post. It did not sound contradictory to my previously raised flag.

I wouldn't have clicked on it, if it said <kbd>Looks fine</kbd>. Because the post wasn't fine, which is why I raised the flag in the first place. I think that's a much better label for the button.

Comment: What's the difference between, "No action needed", and, "Looks fine"?  They basically imply the same action; don't do anything to this post.

Comment: I think much of it just requires remembering the context you're in.  You're looking at it from a, "I've already done something here, I don't have to do anything else" global aspect, whereas the review queues are done in a vacuum.  The only context is the action you are currently undertaking.

Comment: There's certainly some confusion there, but I don't see any value in renaming it.  They mean the same in the context provided.

Comment: I think a better option would be to not allow you to review posts you've already flagged.  That's already part of the process for most queues, so expanding it to the late answers or first post queues would solve that.

Answer (score 3):

"No action needed" means that the post is fine as it is and does not need any actions to make it better. It's pretty easy to figure that out.

As for flagging it outside of the queue, why not just flag it within the queue? That's why the "flag" button is still shown. If you did flag it outside of the queue, you already took an action so "no action needed" wouldn't really make sense. In these cases, just reload the page and press "Done".